# Symfony router problem after upgrading pimcore app from 6.9 to 10.6

Tags: symfony, routes, pimcore

I'm stuck in totally not working [Pimcore](https://pimcore.com/en) after upgrade from 6.9 to 10.6 (earlier upgraded from 6.6 to 6.9 without bigger problems). It is also update of Symfony from 4 to 5

Unfortunately right now, I'm totally stuck with 500 error, and I think it's connected with routing.

```
[Sat Aug 05 17:21:41.349429 2023] [core:error] [pid 25751] [client 68.148.xx.xx:58204] 
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. 
Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. 
Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

and

```
[Sat Aug 05 17:21:41.349436 2023] [core:debug] [pid 25751] core.c(3857): [client 68.148.xx.xx:58204] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index_test.php
[Sat Aug 05 17:21:41.349439 2023] [core:debug] [pid 25751] core.c(3857): [client 68.148.xx.xx:58204] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index_test.php
[Sat Aug 05 17:21:41.349442 2023] [core:debug] [pid 25751] core.c(3857): [client 68.148.xx.xx:58204] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index_test.php
[Sat Aug 05 17:21:41.349444 2023] [core:debug] [pid 25751] core.c(3857): [client 68.148.xx.xx:58204] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index_test.php
[Sat Aug 05 17:21:41.349447 2023] [core:debug] [pid 25751] core.c(3857): [client 68.148.xx.xx:58204] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index_test.php
[Sat Aug 05 17:21:41.349449 2023] [core:debug] [pid 25751] core.c(3857): [client 68.148.xx.xx:58204] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index_test.php
```

## my config

```
$ cat config/routes.yaml 
_pimcore:
    resource: "@PimcoreCoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

app:
    resource: "../src/Controller/"
    type: annotation
```

```
$ cat src/Resources/config/routing.yml 
_pimcore_service_robots_txt:
    path: /robots.txt
    defaults: { _controller: Pimcore\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\PublicServicesController::robotsTxtAction }

_pimcore_service_common_files:
    path: /{filename}
    defaults: { _controller: Pimcore\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\PublicServicesController::commonFilesAction }
    requirements:
        filename: '(robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|favicon\.ico|browserconfig\.xml|wpad\.dat|\.crl)'

_pimcore_service_common_files_apple_touch_icon:
    path: /{filename}
    defaults: { _controller: Pimcore\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\PublicServicesController::commonFilesAction }
    requirements:
        filename: 'apple\-touch\-icon.*'

_pimcore_service_thumbnail:
    path: '{prefix}{type}-thumb__{assetId}__{thumbnailName}/{filename}'
    defaults: { _controller: Pimcore\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\PublicServicesController::thumbnailAction}
    requirements:
        prefix: '.*'
        type: 'video|image'
        assetId: '\d+'
        thumbnailName: '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+'
        filename: '.*'

_fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing-sf4.xml"

# auto loads routes from all bundles in Resources/config/pimcore/routing.yml
_pimcore_bundle_auto:
    resource: .
    type: pimcore_bundle
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    LogLevel debug
    SuexecUserGroup "#1004" "#1004"
    ServerName [abc]
    ServerAlias www.[abc]
    ServerAlias mail.[abc]
    ServerAlias webmail.[abc]
    ServerAlias admin.[abc]
    DocumentRoot /home/[abc]/public_html/basic/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/[abc]_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/[abc]_access_log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/[abc]/cgi-bin/
    ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/[abc]/cgi-bin/
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
    <Directory /home/[abc]/public_html/basic/public>
        # Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
        Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.1
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.2
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.4
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php8.0
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php8.1
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php8.2
        FCGIWrapper /home/[abc]/fcgi-bin/php8.1.fcgi .php
        FCGIWrapper /home/[abc]/fcgi-bin/php7.1.fcgi .php7.1
        FCGIWrapper /home/[abc]/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php7.2
        FCGIWrapper /home/[abc]/fcgi-bin/php7.4.fcgi .php7.4
        FCGIWrapper /home/[abc]/fcgi-bin/php8.0.fcgi .php8.0
        FCGIWrapper /home/[abc]/fcgi-bin/php8.1.fcgi .php8.1
        FCGIWrapper /home/[abc]/fcgi-bin/php8.2.fcgi .php8.2
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/[abc]/cgi-bin>
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.[abc]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://[abc]:20000/ [R]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.[abc]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://[abc]:7419/ [R]
    RewriteRule ".*" "-" [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]    
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php7.1
    RemoveHandler .php7.2
    RemoveHandler .php7.4
    RemoveHandler .php8.0
    RemoveHandler .php8.1
    RemoveHandler .php8.2
    <Files awstats.pl>
        AuthName "[abc] statistics"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /home/[abc]/.awstats-htpasswd
        require valid-user
    </Files>
    IPCCommTimeout 31
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
</VirtualHost>
```

All migrations have been done correctly:

```
$ ./bin/console doctrine:migrations:up-to-date --prefix=Pimcore\\Bundle\\CoreBundle

                                                                                                                        
 [OK] Up-to-date! No migrations to execute.
```

```
$ cat composer.json
{
  "name": "pimcore/skeleton",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "sort-packages": true,
    "process-timeout": 0
  },
  "require": {
    "php-http/guzzle7-adapter": "^0.1.1",
    "pimcore/pimcore": "^10.2"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "^4.1.12",
    "codeception/module-symfony": "^1"
  },
  "suggest": {
    "pimcore/data-hub": "Universal data interface for GraphQL, CSV and other formats"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/",
      "Pimcore\\Model\\DataObject\\": "var/classes/DataObject"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": "Pimcore\\Composer::postCreateProject",
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::postInstall",
      "@pimcore-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::postUpdate",
      "@pimcore-scripts",
      "Pimcore\\Composer::executeMigrationsUp",
      "@pimcore-scripts"
    ],
    "pimcore-scripts": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::clearCache",
      "Pimcore\\Composer::installAssets"
    ]
  }
}
```

this pimcore instance serve just an document library. Can somebody help me and maybe show proper config files? Thank You

done full upgrade with instructions based on here https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Installation_and_Upgrade/Updating_Pimcore/V6_to_V10